# How does Visual Studio's "Add Service Reference" deserialize objects?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, serialization

How does `Visual Studio 2013` deserialize objects when you use `Add Service Reference` on a project? I ask because I have the following class:

```
    public class RTMImagePackage
    {
        private int maxImages = 15;

        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public int MaxImages
        {
            get { return this.maxImages; }
            private set { this.maxImages = value; }
        }

        [OnDeserialized]
        void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext c)
        {
            if (maxImages == 0)
            {
                maxImages = 15;
            }
        }
    }
```

If I self-host using local IIS and then create a separate project and add this WCF service using `Add Service Reference`, any new instance of `RTMImagePackage` always has a `MaxImages` value of 0, even though I set it to 15 in multiple places, even inside a method prefaced with `OnDeserialized`.

If I throw in some breakpoints, I can see that the `OnDeserialized` method is never even called on the web service side, even if I try to update the service reference with the breakpoint in place.

Basically I am trying to guarantee that the client-side will always have `MaxImages` set to 15 when it generates the proxy class **WITHOUT** having to use partial classes. Is there a clear way to do this? I've checked other answers and their approach was to use `OnDeserialized` or `OnDeserializing` but that doesn't seem to be working for me.

Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio has no way of probing information about your underlying .NET classes using the Add Service Reference wizard<sup>1</sup>. All it has to go on is the WSDL that your WCF service generates, and that WSDL is not going to have any way of saying that one of the data members one of your service's concrete classes has a backing field with an initial value of 15.

Also, your client has no way of knowing that your class' `OnDeserialized` method sets that backing field to 15 if it is currently 0 during deserialization. `OnDeserialized` is a method that runs when the service *recieves* data from the client. The `OnDeserialized` method's behavior is not exposed as part of your service's interface.

From what I can ascertain, I don't see any way of indicating a custom default value in the WCF interface, and all the advice I can find on using custom default values recommend the `OnDeserialized` approach that you are already using.

However, it appears that if you use ChannelFactories rather than the proxies that Add Service Reference generates, your client application can use .NET definitions for your service data objects and these can be shared between your service and your client. In other words, your client can instantiate instances of `RTMImagePackage` that are defined in a shared assembly, rather than use service proxy classes. This should allow you to do things like including default values and other things that could not be ascertained purely from the WSDL.

More information on ChannelFactories can be found here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/558163/Difference-between-Proxy-and-Channel-Factory-in-WC

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, your service's interface shouldn't be defined in a `class` in the first place. It should be defined in an `interface`.

Comment: Thanks for all the input/help. Question though, you say that the service's interface should be defined in an interface. I already have done that. The example that I posted in the original post was one of the DataMember classes that the service and interface were using. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @user1806716 I think that's what I meant. If your `DataContract` is defined on an `interface`, then that is the correct approach. That interface defines all of the information that VS could possibly obtain via Add Service Reference. The concrete implementation is behind the scenes and not exposed to the outside world, and that is by design.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the `OnDeserialized` method is intended to be triggered, so I won't speak to that.

Basic serialization requires public `get` and `set` accessors. You've got a public `get`, but your `set` is private. Set both of these to public and your object should serialize correctly.